# DateTime not working for dates before 1970

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

PHP v 5.6.2

I need to convert dates such as 18-Jul-46 to give me 18/07/1946 and no amount of DateTime functions work correctly. (As strtotime wont work for dates before 1970). They all end up giving 18/07/2046 which is incorrect.

Codes I tried so far:

```
$date = new DateTime("18-Jul-46");
$date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Another one with DateTime

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y', "18-Jul-46");
$date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Earlier also tried,

```
$date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('18-Jul-46'));
```

None of them gave me the correct format. Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using a 4 digit year. Anything with 2 digits is treated as after 1970, aka the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer doesn't know whether you mean 2000 or 1900. You can just take the last 2 digits of the year and put "19" before like:

```
$date = new DateTime("18-Jul-46");
$date->format('d/m/19y');
```

If you want to use 2000 as well, this code will use the closest number to 1970

```
$date = new DateTime("18-Jul-20");
$date->format('d/m/Y');
$t1 = $date->format('19y');
$t2 = $date->format('20y');

if(abs(1970-$t1)<abs(1970-$t2))
    echo $t1; //Take the 19.. one
else
    echo $t2; //Take the 20.. one
```

But in the end, you can't be sure that even 2030 would be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I don't think I can blindly add 19 to the string as I maybe dealing with dates starting in 2000s too like 2016 so maybe a manual check to know if it's before 1970? It all seems manual but if is the only way out then could do.

Comment: @user7616631 if your data can't be trusted then no code will work for you

Comment: The only thing you can do is to check whether the year is closer to a specific year (e.g. 1970) with 20 before or with 19 before

Comment: @user7616631 "I maybe dealing with dates starting in 2000s too like 2016"  Then how do you know for sure that "18/07/2046" from your question is incorrect?  If you have specific logic that you are applying to know that, then you would need to apply the same logic in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date such as '31-Dec-18", it is ambiguous since it may refer to a date in 1918 or else a date in 2018.  However, if you know that all the dates refer to the 1900s, then code such as the following is feasible given a two-digit year:

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime();
$formatted = "";
$arrFormattedBDays = [];
$birthdays = ['18-Jul-46','19-Aug-47','1-Jan-19','31-Dec-18'];
foreach ($birthdays as $b){
   list($d,$m,$y) = explode("-",$b);
   $y = '19'.$y;
   $dt = new DateTime("$d-$m-$y");
   $formatted = $dt->format('d/m/Y');
   $arrFormattedBDays[] = $formatted;
}
var_dump($arrFormattedBDays);

Output:

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "18/07/1946"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "19/08/1947"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "01/01/1919"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "31/12/1918"
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/UepcO)

Otherwise, by default DateTime creates a date object based on the current year which you may format according to the truth you seek to perpetuate; see [here](https://3v4l.org/LcS5X). Note: if you know that the dates all occur in the 20th century, i.e. 1901-2000, then you may amend this code by adding in a little logic; see [here](https://3v4l.org/Mpf26).